# Get facebook access token with java code

Tags: java, eclipse, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I have 2 questions:

- 1. I am trying to get access token through java code and not through Facebook developers site.
     Does anyone have idea how can I do it?
- 2. is it possible to get longer access token that expires after more than 1 hour ?

I read about some options but not something that is possible to me as simple user in Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

This article in the Facebook docs explains everything you need to know about Access Tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

An App Access Token can be used without User authorization, for every other Token you need authorization: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2

I suggest trying one of the third party SDKs for Java: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/other-sdks

App Access Tokens are valid forever, Extended Page Tokens too. User Tokens can only be extended to 60 days max, by default they are valid for only 2 hours.

Comment: i have tried it but got nothing. do you have a code example?

Comment: "got nothing" is not really a sufficient error description. sorry, but stackoverflow is not a platform where you get code, we help with specific problems, but you are the one who needs to do the work ;)

Comment: I dont know how to do this by code, What's described in the website is url requests. I work with eclipse java and dont know how do do it. thurthermore even when i did get the token by entering the correct url for extending the token - the token didnt work propertly

Comment: what do you mean by "didn´t work properly"? did you debug it in the acces token debugger? > https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/